# What causes a synchronization lock to get stuck?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, nachos

I have this simple code, it's simply a testing case

```
        try
    {
        synchronized(this) {
        while(number != 4)
        {
            System.out.println("Waiting...");
            this.wait();
        }
        number = 4;
        this.notifyAll();
        }
        

    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {}
```

Of what I know regarding use of the wait() method, once wait is invoked, what comes after should be done. However I can't see to get the wait to end in this case. I have attempted to place a second synchronized block but that doesn't seem to work.

Do you know what could be causing the wait to hang? I looked up deadlocking but that seems to be an entirely different matter.

Comment: You need another thread calling `notify` to let `wait` continue.

Comment: where are you incrementing/decrementig the "number" such that number!=4. You havent provided any details of the number ??

Answer (score 0):

Think u better get some idea from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-notify)

then modify your code accordingly, as long there is no another thread is running.

> The wait() method causes the current thread to wait indefinitely until another thread >either invokes notify() for this object or notifyAll().

Answer (score 0):

> Do you know what could be causing the wait to hang?

You have a loop that's waiting for `number` to be set to 4. No code is executed that sets `number` to 4.  Therefore the loop waits forever.

```
    while(number != 4)
    {
        System.out.println("Waiting...");
        this.wait();
    }

    /* you can't get here until some other thread sets number to 4. */
    number = 4;
    this.notifyAll();
    }
```

The `wait` call does not terminate until some other code calls `notify`, and then when you wake up out of the `wait`, you'll loop back again unless `number` is now 4.

You can't have a thread simultaneously be in `wait` **and** executing the code that issues the `notify`.  And if `wait` didn't wait, it would not be useful.

Not intending to be rude, but the problem here seems to be a lack of understanding of sequential execution of program code.